# Create a new user on Webform submission

Tags: webforms

I have a Drupal 8 website with an application form built with Webform. I would like to be able to auto create a user when the webform is submitted using details from the webform, so the person filling in the application can log-in and check the status of their application. I've seen several options online but all are for Drupal 7 and the modules used are not available for Drupal 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use hook_form_alter to add an extra submit handler and there you can create a new user by using the $form_state data. Check the link how to create new user : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197484/how-do-i-programmatically-create-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own WebformHandler to do so. Just extend WebformHandlerBase and write your code into the `postSave()` function. Here is a little example: https://gist.github.com/mharmuth/0ab021d5b65e4cab7c6efec951fc59e9

This class has to be stored in your custom module in the directory `your_custom_module/src/Plugin/WebformHanlder/CreateUserHandler.php`

After creating this handler, you will be able to add it in your webform under "Email/Handlers".

Hope this helps ;)